# Implementing Google Drive Support for my desktop application

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I developed a desktop application that saves projects locally to disk. Each project is a directory that consists out of many files. If certain files are missing the project is corrupt.

I want to add Google Drive support to my desktop application, so the user can load and save projects directly to the cloud. For clarification, the desktop application talks directly to the users Google Drive. There is **no** 3rd-party webservice involved.

I want to make the installation process as easy as possible for the user. I know the user can generate an API key for his account, but this is to technical for my target audience.

My question is, can I create a Google Drive App that shows up in the market place, that my desktop application can use to access the files on the users drive? Or is the market place meant to be only for 3rd party web-services that can access someones account?

**TLDR;** I want my desktop application being able to access Google Drive files. Is it possible to create a 1-2 click installation process that my app can access these files? Setting up an API key is too complicated for my users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to make the installation process as easy as possible for the user. I know the user can generate an API key for his account, but this is to technical for my target audience.

First off an API key is only used to access public data.  You will need to have your user [authorize](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth) your application access their google drive account using Oauth2.

You will need to create a project on google cloud console and create Oauth2 credentials which will allow your application to request access of the user.

> I want my desktop application being able to access Google Drive files. Is it possible to create a 1-2 click installation process that my app can access these files? Setting up an API key is too complicated for my users.

Its not exactly one click but a user will have to be signed in to their google account and then click the authorize button.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is actually already the answer! Just to be sure, I create an app through the Console and my app connects itself to the users Google Drive? How does Google recognize my desktop app as the app I registered?

Comment: The client id and client secret that you create identify your application to google. https://youtu.be/qwqJcyLQSSQ  these values will need to be released with your application.

Comment: isn't possible to make it automate for signing in and clicking the allow button?

Comment: No that would not allow a user to consent. The user must consent to your access.  If you want to access their private data